# I want to add product to cart screen and show the total price and sub total and with cubit but it does not working

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

> This is Product Models As Dummy Data

**I can not show the price of product**

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class ProductModels extends Equatable {
  final String name;
  final String category;
  final String imageUrl;
  final double price;
  final bool isRecommended;
  final bool isPopular;

  const ProductModels(
      {required this.name,
      required this.category,
      required this.imageUrl,
      required this.price,
      required this.isRecommended,
      required this.isPopular});

  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props =>
      [name, category, imageUrl, price, isRecommended, isPopular];
  static List<ProductModels> products = [
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Pizza',
        category: 'Food',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1565299624946-b28f40a0ae38.webp',
        price: 5.99,
        isRecommended: true,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Pizza',
        category: 'Food',
        imageUrl: 'assets/pizza/foad-roshan-Y6OgisiGBjM-unsplash.jpg',
        price: 5.99,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Pizza',
        category: 'Food',
        imageUrl: 'assets/pizza/masimo-grabar-NzHRSLhc6Cs-unsplash.jpg',
        price: 5.99,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Pizza',
        category: 'Food',
        imageUrl: 'assets/pizza/saahil-khatkhate-kfDsMDyX1K0-unsplash.jpg',
        price: 5.99,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Pizza',
        category: 'Food',
        imageUrl: 'assets/pizza/saundarya-srinivasan-60nzTP7_hMQ-unsplash.jpg',
        price: 5.99,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Pizza',
        category: 'Food',
        imageUrl: 'assets/pizza/shaian-ramesht-exSEmuA7R7k-unsplash.jpg',
        price: 5.99,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Iphone Cover',
        category: 'Covers',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1576107324820-c10884700b6b.webp',
        price: 19.50,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: true),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Iphone Cover',
        category: 'Covers',
        imageUrl:
            'assets/iphone_covers/mark-chan-OPp_l7V2yCQ-unsplash.jpg',
        price: 19.50,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Iphone Cover',
        category: 'Covers',
        imageUrl:
            'assets/iphone_covers/daniel-korpai-qEoKzD2zJjE-unsplash.jpg',
        price: 19.50,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Iphone Cover',
        category: 'Covers',
        imageUrl: 'assets/iphone_covers/21013840.jpg',
        price: 19.50,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Brown coat',
        category: 'Fashion',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1583001809952-61891dfacb98.webp',
        price: 99.99,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: true),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Iphone 11 Pro Max',
        category: 'Electronics',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1592750475338-74b7b21085ab.webp',
        price: 800,
        isRecommended: true,
        isPopular: true),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Air Jordan AJI',
        category: 'Air Jordan Collection',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1597045566677-8cf032ed6634.webp',
        price: 65,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: true),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Orange Juice',
        category: 'Water',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1600271886742-f049cd451bba.webp',
        price: 5,
        isRecommended: false,
        isPopular: true),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Air Pods Pro',
        category: 'Electronics',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1606741965429-8d76ff50bb2f.webp',
        price: 200,
        isRecommended: true,
        isPopular: false),
    const ProductModels(
        name: 'Iphone 12',
        category: 'Electronics',
        imageUrl: 'assets/product_images/photo-1616348436168-de43ad0db179.webp',
        price: 700,
        isRecommended: true,
        isPopular: false),
  ];
}
```

and This is Wish List Models

```
import 'package:e_commerce_app/models/product_models.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

import 'package:e_commerce_app/models/product_models.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class CartModels extends Equatable {
  final List<ProductModels>products;
  const CartModels({this.products=const <ProductModels>[]});

  double get subTotal =>
      products.fold(0, (total, current) => total + current.price);

  String get subTotlaToString => subTotal.toStringAsFixed(2);

  double deliveryFee(subTotal) {
    if (subTotal >= 30) {
      return 0.0;
    } else {
      return 10.0;
    }
  }

  String get deliveryFeeToString => deliveryFee(subTotal).toStringAsFixed(2);

  String freeDelivery(subTotal) {
    if (subTotal >= 30) {
      return 'You Have  Free Delivery';
    } else {
      double missing = 30.0 - subTotal;
      return 'Add\$ ${missing.toStringAsFixed(2)} For Free Delivery';
    }
  }

  String get freeDeliveryToString => freeDelivery(subTotal);
  double total(subTotal,deliveryFee){
    return subTotal+deliveryFee(subTotal);
  }
String get totalToString=>total(subTotal, deliveryFee).toStringAsFixed(2);
  @override
// TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [products];
}
```

> i want to show the price of product and subtotal and total with cubit not bloc

[this is cart Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IffaJ.png)

> this is my cubitStates

```
part of 'cart_cubit.dart';

abstract class CartState  {}

class CartInitial extends CartState {}

class CartLoading extends CartState {}

class CartLoaded extends CartState {
  final ProductModels productList;
   CartLoaded(this.productList,);
}
class CartError extends CartState {}
```

> and this is cubit

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:e_commerce_app/models/cart_models.dart';
import 'package:e_commerce_app/models/product_models.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'cart_state.dart';

class CartCubit extends Cubit<CartState> {
  CartCubit() : super(CartInitial());

  List<ProductModels> productList = [];

  void getCartData(ProductModels productModels) async {
    emit(CartLoading());
     await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    try {
       productList.add(productModels) ;
      emit(CartLoaded((productModels)));
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

1. I want to add product into cart screen with price details
2. Add and remove items

Comment: what do you mean "it does not working"?? any error, logs, description...

Comment: it return the products with out any data of pricing

Comment: you should provide main widget code, where getCartData method is used

Comment: How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, this information is still not enough to solve the problem. for example, it is not clear where and how the method is used `getCartData`.

then, looks like you have a little mess here. so to try fixed your problem, you should first get rid of mess.

fix name `ProductModels` to `Product`.
**why is it plural?**.

same thing with `CartModels`.

then in state you will understand more correctly:
you want to pass product model or list???

> 

```
class CartLoaded extends CartState {
  final ProductModels productList;
   CartLoaded(this.productList,);
}
```

and then in cubit it will be more clear what exactly you want to emit in state: list(why not just `CartModels` if so??) or model `Product`:

```
...

    try {
           productList.add(productModels) ;
          emit(CartLoaded((productModels)));
        } 

...
```

Comment: When i click the add button it receive the product information and when i add more products the total value it was not show and total number

Comment: may be it because you emit CartLoaded with one model and not list? I mention it in the answer above.